# The x-axis is stationary when the blit parameter is True

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

There is a sine wave that I want to animate. I have achieved the task, with the "Blit" parameter being set to "False". Curious about what the "Blit" parameter does to the whole animation process, in the context of my code, I set "Blit" to "True". I noticed that while the function returns the Line 2D, the x-axis remains stationary. I wonder if it due to the fact that - when Blit is set to true - it redraws only the artists returned by the function and nothing else.

**Previous Stackoverflow answers I went through **
[This is a stackOverflow post I went through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661786/funcanimation-object-has-no-attribute-resize-id) and [How to animate an expanding circle with blit = true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35068396/matplotlib-funcanimation-error-when-blit-true)  where the Blit parameter is set to True. Going through the said posts, I modified the return statement as follows:

`return line, ax`
But this caused the entire axis to disappear. Can someone point out the mistake in my code?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation


x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y_plot1_fourier = np.sin(x)

x_l_plot = 0
x_u_plot = 5


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim([x_l_plot, x_u_plot])
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)


line, = ax.plot([], [], label='y_plot1_fourier', c='r', linewidth=2)


def func(n):

    line.set_data(x[:n], y_plot1_fourier[:n])


    if x[n] > x_u_plot - 3:
        ax.set_xlim(x[n] - (x_u_plot - 3), x[n] + 3)
    else:
        ax.set_xlim(x_l_plot, x_u_plot)


    return line, ax


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=len(x), interval=200, blit=True)

plt.show()
```